# How to make the parent div adjust in size to contain the CSS-Rotated child div?

Tags: javascript, css

The Title says it all: "How to make the parent div adjust in size to contain the CSS-Rotated child div?"

This is what I get currently:
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="rotator">
        <h1>TEXT</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rotator {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: rgb(130, 310, 130);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 500px;

  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/viyacaji/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

So, is there anyway to make the parent resize with child?
A CSS only solution would be best. If that's impossible, what's the best javascript way to do that?
*Should support IE9*

**Based on @misterManSam's suggestion** I update the live example to show the solution.
[found here](http://jsbin.com/viyacaji/17/edit?html,css,js,output)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width of the `div.container` when rotated. Add negative margin and left margin to `#rotator.deg90`in CSS.

[Look at this example :)](http://jsbin.com/viyacaji/16/edit)

Javascript

```
function to90() {
   var elm = document.getElementById("rotator");
   console.log(elm);
   elm.className = "deg90";

//add these lines
   document.getElementById('container').style.width = "500px";
   document.getElementById('container').style.height = "200px";
}
```

CSS

```
#rotator.deg90 {
  /*add this*/
  margin-top: -150px;
  margin-left: 200px;

 -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
 -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
 transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For now I am going with your direction only implementing it as a generic solution:
parent.style.width = (elm.clientHeight * Math.sin(rad) + elm.clientWidth * Math.cos(rad))+ "px";

If there is no better solution I will mark yours as the answer.
http://jsbin.com/viyacaji/17/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score -1):

Here you go: http://jsbin.com/viyacaji/11/edit

Just rotate the container in the jS functions, don't move the rotator div. Because basically, what you're trying to achieve is the same as when you rotate the parent div.

Any query?

Comment: Here's the problem - I want the parent's width to fit the rotated child. Rotating the the parent with CSS will not change the width.